# Algorithm to select outer edge of 2d grid array c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine, multidimensional-array

I have created a 2D grid in c# using the following code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        array.add(new vector3(i,0,j);
    }
}
```

This will give me a list of co-ordinates that I can use as a 2d grid. 
Using this list of grid locations, I would like to select and return only the outer edge coordinates (possibly creating a second list of coordinates).

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 1, 1, 1, 0
0, 1, 1, 1, 0
0, 1, 1, 1, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

e.g. I would like to get a list of the coordinates for all of the zeros locations above and add these to a second list. How would be best to tackle this?

My attempt used a variety of nested loops which also created duplicates. The selected answer looks better than a nested loop and will return the values I am after.

Comment: What have you tried?  I see your initialization code, but I don't see any attempts at finding the coordinates

Comment: `I just cannot seem to write the loop efficiently.` Efficiency is your last problem. First show us what you have tried inefficiently

Comment: @BrianPeach Your question is a little unclear. Your sample data shows 5 rows and 5 columns. Which of those **specific** cells are you trying to return, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use some conditions on nested loops to rich the result, but as you mentioned, you want an effective loop.
faster way is using two simple loops:

```
1, 1, 1, 1, 1
2, 0, 0, 0, 2
2, 0, 0, 0, 2
2, 0, 0, 0, 2
1, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

this loop gives you 1s :

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    list.Add(array[i][0]);
    list.Add(array[i][array.length-1]);
}
```

and this one gives you 2s:

```
for(int i = 1; i < array.length -1; i++){
    list.Add(array[0][i]);
    list.Add(array[array.length-1][i]);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It seems you want the coordinates of all grid cells whose value is 0 and which have a neighboring cell whose value is 1. So, you need to visit each grid cell, check these two conditions, and if they pass add the coordinates to a list. Be careful in calculating the coordinates of neighboring cells when at an edge of the grid.

Comment: Just wait till you have enough reputations and then post this as a comment.